# Groovy "java.lang.Integer.readLine() is applicable for argument types: () values: []" error

Tags: java, groovy, io

I am trying to write a brief code that would read a few lines from console. This is my code:

```
System.in.withReader {
    int a = it.readLine() as int
    (1..a).each {
        int b = it.readLine() as int
        def sum = 0
        (0..(b-1)).each {d ->
            sum+=(-1)^d/(2*d+1)
        }
        println sum/4
    }
}
```

This is input from the console:

```
1
20
```

And this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.Integer.readLine() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I have a feeling that somehow Groovy does not get inputs from console. When I tried debugging it did not allow me to enter anything into console.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `each` shadows the `it` from the `withReader`:

```
System.in.withReader { /* implicit it */
    int a = it.readLine() as int
    (1..a).each { /* implicit it */
        int b = it.readLine() as int // this `it` now is an int from (1..a)
```

Give the inner `it` a name (like you do later with `d`) and the original `it` will remain the reader.  To further untangle this you might even want to give the reader its own var name.

Comment: Ah, I see - it overrides "it". Correct?

Comment: yes, without naming it for yourself, groovy uses `it` and shadows the outer `it`.